# Controlling Ok SoftKeyboard buttons Android

Tags: android, android-keypad

I set an Ok key on soft android keyboard when i click on the edittext shown below:

```
 <EditText
            android:id="@+id/rlMP3SeekContainer"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/text_rougea"
            android:singleLine="true" 
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/hint_deezer_search"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/eight_dp"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/eight_dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textColorHint="@color/gray_text"
            android:textSize="@dimen/twelve_sp" />
```

When the keyboard appear i want the user when clicking on the ok button do something. but how can i override the ok button on the keyboard to do whatever i want

Answer (score 21):

You need to implement the OnEditorActionListener:

```
yourEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(
        new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
          if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            /* your code here */
          }
    }
});
```